# How to Handle Relative/Full URLs in Pytohn?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, url

As we know and html page may include link in different ways, for example we can include an image like this:

Suppose we are currently at: https://example.com/folder

`https://example.com/images/picture.jpg` which resolves to the same.

`/images/picture.jpg` which resolves to: `https://example.com/images/picture.jpg`.

`images/picture.jpg` which resolves to: `https://example.com/folder/images/picture.jpg`.

How can python Handle all those cases for me?

---

**My previous approach (which is wrong):**

```
response = requests.get(url)
...
for link in links:
    if link.startswith('/'):
        print(url+link)
    else:
        print(url)
```

Another reason for why it's wrong is because when visiting `https://example.com` we might get redirected to: `https://example.com/homepage?ignore=yes` so the base url isn't any longer the visited one but `https://example.com/homepage/`

Answer (score 0):

The Python `urllib` module has a function that can do this for you: `urllib.parse.urljoin`.  You provide the base, and the potentially relative URL, and it will give you the absolute result.  There are a lot of special cases, so it's best to let the tool do it.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse

Comment: Hi, I have few questions please: Q1) will it handle the difference between example 2 (the one with /) and example 3?   Q2) by the base you mean the url of the current page (after redirection)? In this case will it handle such cases where base contains parameters and delete them before forming the whole link?

Comment: Look, URLs are not handled randomly.  RFC 1808 specifies exactly how browsers need to handle relative URLs.  `urllib` implements RFC 1808, among others, and the documentation states.